# C# HttpClient GetAsync exception "The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response"

Tags: c#, exception, httpclient, getasync

This seems to be a random issue. Sometimes the GetAsync successfully gets a response (200/OK). Other times it throws an exception.
I'm thinking it has something to do with the "Transfer-Encoding: chunked".
BTW...the streamed files are anywhere from 8MB to 300MB

Here is my pertinent code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
try
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
    };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "multipart/related; type=\"application/dicom\"");
    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Response:[{response}]");
        return false;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception:[{e.Message}] | Stack:[{e.StackTrace}] | InnerEx:[{e.InnerException}]");
    return false;
}
```

Here's the HttpResponseMessage when GetAsync is successful (200/OK):

```
{
  "Version": {
    "Major": 1,
    "Minor": 1,
    "Build": -1,
    "Revision": -1,
    "MajorRevision": -1,
    "MinorRevision": -1
  },
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [ "multipart/related; boundary=Boundary_77_676776408_1611644859244; type=\"application/dicom\"" ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Key": "Transfer-Encoding",
      "Value": [ "chunked" ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "MIME-Version",
      "Value": [ "1.0" ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Date",
      "Value": [ "Tue, 26 Jan 2021 07:07:39 GMT" ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Proxy-Connection",
      "Value": [ "Keep-Alive" ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Connection",
      "Value": [ "Keep-Alive" ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Age",
      "Value": [ "0" ]
    }
  ],
  "RequestMessage": {
    "Version": {
      "Major": 2,
      "Minor": 0,
      "Build": -1,
      "Revision": -1,
      "MajorRevision": -1,
      "MinorRevision": -1
    },
    "Content": null,
    "Method": { "Method": "GET" },
    "RequestUri": "http://1.2.3.4:5007/blah/blah1/11/blah2/22/blah3/33",
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Accept",
        "Value": [ "multipart/related; type=\"application/dicom\"" ]
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {}
  },
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Other times there is no response and an exception is thrown:

Exception:[The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.] | Stack:[   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ThrowInvalidHttpResponse()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream.ReadChunkFromConnectionBuffer(Int32 maxBytesToRead, CancellationTokenRegistration cancellationRegistration)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.HttpConnectionResponseContent.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at myapp.GetBlahAsync(Uri uri, String newFileName) in C:\blah\Svc.cs:line 97] | InnerEx:[]

Answer (score 0):

is because you need deserialize response

```
   HttpResponseMessage response = null;
try
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
    };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "multipart/related; type=\"application/dicom\"");
    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
        var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(responseData, options);

        Console.WriteLine($"Response:[{result }]");
        return result;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception:[{e.Message}] | Stack:[{e.StackTrace}] | InnerEx:[{e.InnerException}]");
    return false;
}
```

for convert your json to c# class use this site [Json to c# class](https://json2csharp.com/)

```
  // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
        public class Version    {
            public int Major { get; set; } 
            public int Minor { get; set; } 
            public int Build { get; set; } 
            public int Revision { get; set; } 
            public int MajorRevision { get; set; } 
            public int MinorRevision { get; set; } 
        }
    
        public class Header    {
            public string Key { get; set; } 
            public List<string> Value { get; set; } 
        }
    
        public class Content    {
            public List<Header> Headers { get; set; } 
        }
    
        public class Method    {
            public string Method { get; set; } 
        }
    
        public class Properties    {
        }
    
        public class RequestMessage    {
            public Version Version { get; set; } 
            public object Content { get; set; } 
            public Method Method { get; set; } 
            public string RequestUri { get; set; } 
            public List<Header> Headers { get; set; } 
            public Properties Properties { get; set; } 
        }
    
        public class Root    {
            public Version Version { get; set; } 
            public Content Content { get; set; } 
            public int StatusCode { get; set; } 
            public string ReasonPhrase { get; set; } 
            public List<Header> Headers { get; set; } 
            public RequestMessage RequestMessage { get; set; } 
            public bool IsSuccessStatusCode { get; set; } 
        }
```

or in visual studio in **Edit-->Paste Special-->Paste JSON As Classes**

Comment: The program flow doesn't get past the GetAsync(). It skips out to the catch.

Comment: @MartinN is it possible you can share the site or not?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It's an endpoint on a private network at another company. I've only seen the success response. No non-200/OK responses because GetAsync throws the exception.

Comment: @MartinN ok, change this `response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);` for this `response = await httpClient.GetAsync("your_url_end_endpoint");`

Comment: It works against our server. Just not the external server. Actually it used to work then the external company wanted us to modify the "Accept" header value to "multipart/related; type=\"application/dicom\"")

Comment: @MartinN try again in postman, how to send headers using postman? is working in postman? Is it possible that you add a screenshot of the header, and see if the request from postman is successful?